# Set color of matInput outline dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-material, outline, mat-input, ng-deep

I've got a basic Angular Material input field like this:

```
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <input matInput type="text">
            <button matSuffix mat-icon-button>
              <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </mat-form-field>
```

And want to change the color of the outline. For a fix color I found this example:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
    .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use the value of a variable (in a ngFor loop) as the color of the outline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[style.--CSS-VARIABLE-NAME]` in the `html`. Then consume it in the `SCSS` or `CSS` using `var(--CSS-VARIABLE-NAME)`.

For more info, please read this: [https://angular.io/guide/class-binding#:~:text=To%20create%20a%20single%20style,following%3A%20%5Bstyle.width%5D%3D%22width%22](https://angular.io/guide/class-binding#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20single%20style,following%3A%20%5Bstyle.width%5D%3D%22width%22).

### example.component.ts

```js
@Component({
 // ...
})
export class Example {

  public myColor = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

}
```

### example.component.html

```js
<ng-container *ngFor="let color of myColors">

  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" [style.--custom-color]="color">
    <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
    <input matInput />
  </mat-form-field>

</ng-container>
```

### example.component.scss

```scss
:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  color: var(--custom-color);
}
```